# Execute CGI script in the same webpage

Tags: html, cgi

I'm about to finish my project.. I only need a minor thing but it's giving me lots of problems.

I have a server running inside my Raspberry Pi. The server displays a webpage with some buttons and a video streaming. It work's really, the only problem is that when I press one of the images, a CGI Script is run. But it opens a new web page.

**I'd like to execute the CGI script but staying in the same page (index.html). How could I achieve this?**

Thanks in advance

PD: I tried to use this inside my CGI but it's still not working:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 gpio -p write 201 1

 echo "Status: 204 No Content"
 echo "Content-type: text/plain"
 echo ""
```

Comment: The technique you are looking for is called Ajax. It is normally performed [using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: I'll have a look. Thank you for pointing me the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX, and the easiest way to do that is to use the jQuery library which makes it all portable and simple.

Start [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) , read it through by clicking "Next Chapter" and do the "Try it Yourself" examples.